# Ubuntu on Galaxy Tab 3

Tags: samsung

I'm trying to get my Galaxy Tab 3 to run on Ubuntu. Can anyone help guide me in installing and running it?

Comment: Galaxy Tab 3 already runs Android 4.4.2 which is a Linux based operating system. You'd be best served sticking with that I think.

Answer (score 1):

## Android 4.4.2

The Galaxy Tab 3 7.0 was released with Android 4.1.2 Jelly Bean. But the Wi-Fi model has also received the Android 4.4.2 Operating System Update. Samsung has customized the interface with its TouchWiz UX software.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Tab_3_7.0

---

Because Android, like Ubuntu is a Linux based Operating System I would recommend you stay with the native OS that comes with Galaxy Tab.

Although Ubuntu announced Unity 8 Interface as the unified interface between Desktops, Cell Phones and Tablets the project has been canceled so you would likely get more programs and better support through Android.